# Repeatedly error out of memory in weblogic 12

Tags: java, weblogic

Some days ago we move our application from wls  10.3.5.0 (Java6) to wls 12.1.3.0.0(Java7). We have test server  where every day bamboo agent deploy couple of application and run some test against this server. Problem is when we upgrade to wls 12 then there is error out of memory exception after 2-3 days:

```
Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '166' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '35' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

in wls 10 we dont have this problem. In web start I set up this parameters: 
`-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xss1m` but the error still occurs.

Comment: Looks like permgen leak. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/what-is-a-permgen-leak.html

Comment: I dont think so. I think this happens because we are deploying couple off application (20) every day. We have also development server where we deploy application just once and here it runs with no problem

Comment: PermGen leak is totally related to frequent deployments.

Comment: and there is no optimalization how to prevent it ?

Comment: You can either restart server after deployment or carefully examine your application and used libraries to find permgen leak source and fix it

Comment: PermGen generally relates to class loading, which would definitely be an issue deploying 20 applications. Are you deleting old applications before redeploying? You can monitor your server with jconsole to see how the memory and total classes numbers increase as you deploy

Answer (score 1):

1 Confirm the server is indeed using 512m of perm space.
2 ensure you explicitly undeploy and then deploy your new version of applications. If needed explicitly delete old app and even remove temp and stage folder contents.

You would run out of perm space when wls thinks it needs all the classes old and new.